# jdoconfig file - what folder should I put it in, in android studio?

Tags: android, jdo, google-cloud-endpoints

The tutorials and everything that I read tells me that I need to put jdoconfig.xml into the "war/Meta-inf/classes" directory, however I don't have a "war" file in android studio!

Where should this file go now?

```
C:\Users\MyUser\AndroidStudioProjects\MyModule\endpoints\target\endpoints-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes ????
```

Comment: what tutorials? what "everything"?

Answer (score 2):

Why not print out the CLASSPATH if you don't understand which of your app server folders is in it? See System java class javadoc for details (`System.getProperty("java.class.path")`). It should show one of those folders you mentioned in the other answer comment in the CLASSPATH
*jdoconfig.xml* has to be in META-INF as the other answer said.

Once you identify the folder that is being included in the classpath then just drop your `jdoconfig.xml` in META-INF under that folder.

Comment: This post could definitely explain better how to tackle the question asked? Please improve the answer if you do know how to help, please be more clear.

Comment: It answers what the user required to know, building on what the other answer starts with. i.e where to put their jdoconfig.xml

Answer (score 0):

Putting such a file in META-INF at the root of the CLASSPATH is where the JDO spec tells you to put that file. The JDO spec is public and always has been. The docs of your JDO provider would likely tell you the exact same thing

Comment: would that be the meta-inf of the endpoint server process or the meta-inf folder in the app's folder?

Comment: The META-INF at the root of the CLASSPATH, which is the only thing the RUNTIME cares about. Your configuration of your webserver or whatever would define which of those go in the CLASSPATH

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise in Android Studio the proper place is here:

```
./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/jdoconfig.xml
```

The path is relative inside the module.